# Why won't this custom font display in Chrome for Windows when in Japanese locale?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, unicode, fonts, character-encoding

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TCg8N/

Basically it's a simple page with some (Japanese) unicode characters and a custom font (via data:uri):

```
<head>
<style>    
body {
    font-family: "customfont";
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "customfont";
    src: url(data:font/ttf;base64,...);
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
&#12362;&#21839;&#21512;&#12379;&#20869;&#23481;&#12434;&#12372;&#35352;&#20837;&#12367;&#12384;&#12373;&#12356;&#12290;
</body>
```

It works on all browsers I have tested except Chrome on Windows (I tried Windows 7, but could be there on other versions as well). To reproduce the issue:

1. Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Region and Language -> Administrative -> Change system locale...
2. Select Japanese (Japan) from the list.
3. Reboot.

Is this a Chrome bug, or could there be something wrong with my font? I tried explicitly setting the charset to UTF-8, but that doesn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to use `unicode-range` descriptor to define your `font-face`.

```
unicode-range: U+0-10FFFF;/* Initial range */
```

> This descriptor defines the set of Unicode codepoints that may be
>   supported by the font face for which it is declared.
>     http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#unicode-range-desc

I'm not sure why Chrome (31 or later) has different behavior from other browsers, but this article might be a clue for it:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=247920

Your code might go like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style> 
body {
   font-family: "customfont";
}
@font-face {
   font-family: "customfont";
   src: local('Arial');/* defining default src */
}
@font-face {
   font-family: "customfont";
   unicode-range: U+007F-FFFF; /* range other than Latin */
   src: url(data:font/ttf;base64,AAE....);
}
</style>
</head>
```

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/jXHfd/3/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does cause the characters to show up, but it does not appear to be the correct font for me. I am running this in Chrome 36.0.1965.0 canary